# GitLab runner use same folder for diffrent environments

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a problem. I have two merge requests from two different branches to the master branch in a project.
Now I want to start an environment in GitLab for each merge request. I do this with a shell executor and I start docker container with `docker run image_name` where I mount the folder from the build process inside the container. Looks like this:
    stages:
      - deploy

```
deploy_stage:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - docker run -d --name ContainerName -v ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}:/var/www/html -e VIRTUAL_HOST=example.com php
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    url: http://example.com
    on_stop: stop_stage
  tags:
    - shell
  except:
    - master

stop_stage:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    - docker stop ContainerName
    - docker rm ContainerName
  when: manual
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    action: stop
  tags:
    - shell
```

Now my problem is that one environment is runng and when a new job runs the checkout/code get overwritten by the new pipeline job and both environments have now the same code but they should be different.

Does anyone have a solution for me how I can configure the gitlab runner to have different checkout folder for each merge request?